# Make minimal linux disk live

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, small-distribution

I was wondering if anyone had a minimal Linux system with nothing but the bare minimum to boot. Is there any tutorials on the web, I couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the smallest possible Linux implementation?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-smallest-possible-linux-implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) that has a graphical interface in around 10 Megabytes. They also have Micro Core Linux which uses a text based console in around 6 Megabytes.

Comment: Tiny core looks nice I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Look at slackware you build it as light or as heavy as you like

Comment: Ill check it out tomorrow. Need sleep :) ima kill myself staying up till 4:30 every morning :|

Comment: Well it's 12:38 here and I'm waiting for a hair cut! Wish I could get back in bed