# What is a free, small Unix/Linux OS?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, small-distribution

I have a spare machine with an 80GB HDD and 512 MB RAM. I want to try a Linux distro that's very small (and free too). What should I try?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-smallest-possible-linux-implementation

Comment: 512MB ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: Exactly the same you are running on your main machine, just tweaked for size/lighter load (e.g, XFCE and not Gnome/KDE).

Answer (score 15):

For a computer with those specs you really don't need to worry about size. You can run Linux on far smaller machines just fine.

A simple option would be Ubuntu - it does most things right out of the box, so while not quite as lean as some other Linuxes, it is an easy one to try out if you have never used one before. If you want, you can even run it off a CD to try before you install.

There is even an [Ubuntu Stackexchange](https://askubuntu.com/q/28965/7163) so you can get assistance easily if required.

Comment: Do you know any Linux system that won't *happily run on that*, or were you playing safe (i.e. there could be, but you don't know)?

Comment: @Tshepang - I have certainly had Debian, Red Hat, Fedora, Ubuntu, Suse and Slack on much lower specced machines. I was just playing safe (as you never know :-)

Comment: But you are aware that the statement can be misleading right, as in you might know of one that won't *happily run on that*. So rather change the statement to something like *I don't think there's any distro that won't happily run on that (I stand to be corrected)*.

Comment: I'm developing software for Unity on a 4 gigabyte USB disk, it runs Ubuntu 11.04 perfectly well, and even after a few weeks of upgrades, I have about 1.5gb of free space. :-)

Comment: @Tshepang - done :-)

Comment: Really guys? What machines did you use? I was trying to get an old laptop running with Debian Squeeze and it complained at the beginning about only 32M of RAM and indeed failed later to get it into a bootable state. It may be helpful to give such actual numbers when telling about how small you can go ...

Comment: 32MB RAM is 8 times less than the specs being discussed here. Ubuntu's official line is 256MB IIRC for a standard install.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I set up some Ubuntu flavors in the last few years. If you like to run Firefox + Thunderbird + OpenOffice simultaneously, you should plan in the direction of 512 MB. Less than 256 MB will not be a fine experience. Then you can go with Opera and Abiword, but a lot of people need a heavyweight office suite.

Comment: @tobyodavies: fair point. Rory's comment, however, sounded like "much lower specced" than discussed here. And I was trying to get the point across, that much lower than that won't even fly with some of the distros that are considered rather lean (like Debian).

Comment: @STATUS - yep, fair point.I have had Suse and Red Hat run just about fine on less that 256MB, and I have Debian running on a 16MM machine in my car (but although you can play pac man on it, a word processor would be right out of the question)

Answer (score 12):

There are several **small** distributions of linux, like **[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org)** or **[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org)**.

But with those machine specs, you don't need such a light-weight distribution. You can install any, like **Debian** or **Ubuntu**... you can check many of them to see which one fits better in the idea you have for that machine at [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com).

**Update:** Just discovered [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html), and seems also a very interesting option for a very small Server/Desktop.

**Update 2, 2013 Review:**

Another 2 options I've found [looking for `old computers` on Distrowach](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=Old%20Computers&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active):

- [AntiX](http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page): Based on Debian Testing. On their [FAQ](http://www.mepisimo.com/antix/Released/antiX-13.1/FAQ/index.html) they say it fits on *0.7GB* if you use just the *core* or *2.8GB* the *full install*
- [CrunchBag](http://crunchbang.org/): Debian based, [CrunchBag](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=crunchbang) primary aim is to produce a stable distribution offering the best possible out-of-the-box [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) experience.

Comment: Love Puppy, it's where my Linux experience started. Thanks Barry for making it possible!

Answer (score 7):

Distributions described as lightweight

[BasicLinux]- A very lightweight distribution capable of running on an Intel 386 and
 3 MB of RAM.

[Absolute Linux]

[Damn Small Linux] - "light enough to power a 486DX with 16MB of Ram"

[Lubuntu]- light weight in comparison to Ubuntu.

[Puppy Linux] - light weight relative to most other Linux distributions.

[SliTaz] - 25 megabyte distribution

[Tiny Core Linux] - 10 megabyte distribution

[Wolvix]

[Xubuntu] - light weight in comparison to Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

[**Source of above**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_Linux)

Have fun!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Lubuntu. For the amount of space that you're going to save, you might as well just use Ubuntu - everything actually works out of the box.

Comment: I can recommend xUbuntu, but won't think other decisions bad. 512 MB is much and could be enough, even for (K)Ubuntu, but it might  get slowly, from update to update, a little weak.

Comment: Xubuntu is really the only one of these that makes sense. The others are more "Running it off a floppy" small.

Comment: Another one: http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/. Also: https://www.archlinux.org/ comes bare-bones by default. Alpine is substantially smaller and lighter-weight but Arch has a much larger community.

Answer (score 4):

You should try the "tinyCore".
This one is so small that you can run it on an Flash with just 128 MB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently running Debian 6 with the Xfce desktop on just such a machine right now. It works very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Use XUbuntu.

It's powerful and yet light.

Use this [download link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/10.10/release/).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I just had to add my 2 cents worth:

1) I would highly recommend [Bodhi Linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/). It has a fantastic user interface (nice eye candy) yet requires only these minimum hardware specs: 300+MHz CPU, 128MB RAM, and 2.5GB hard drive space (see their [about page](http://www.bodhilinux.com/about_bodhi.php))

2) As for a free distribution, you don't have far to look, they are just about all free ;-)

Also, Bodhi is an Ubuntu derivative, meaning it is not only easy to install, but you can benefit from all the packages in the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine on a 4GB USB memory stick with enough space for a copy of VMware player, so I can have a full Linux/X/Eclipse development machine any time I need one.

To create it, I just downloaded a standard Ubuntu VM 'appliance' with most of the right components pre-installed, added a few tweaks, and off I went.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you, is Debian. It's stable and runs well on most architechture.

I have myself Debian on my iBook G4 (30Gb HDD, 256 MB RAM), what could use most of your memory, is the desktop manager. If you only browse on the internet, check emails, chat with some friends, you could install GNOME. If you need more memory, I recommend you Fluxbox, it's a lightweight desktop manager, but it's not easy to use (not always user-friendly).

I've tried Ubuntu, but it's not as lightweight and stable as Debian...But it's more beautiful :)

It's your personal choice, it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) 12.04 works for me, but others have problems installing.

Answer (score -1):

Build your own distro
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/

Comment: -1 LFS is not easy, and it's bound to confuse anyone who has no experience in using GNU/Linux.

Comment: @André Paramés: it's still a proper point matcheek makes. +1

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I don't agree, LFS is not an OS, it's a guide to build them. It doesn't answer the actual question and it will probably confuse OP.

Comment: @André Paramés: well, the question wasn't for a ready-to-use distro. So we keep disagreeing :o)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes, but the question was about "trying" UNIX/Linux. Talk about heads first!

Comment: @Jacob: the educational value would be tremendous. I understand your point, though :)

Comment: You can do this, it's interesting, but not necessary here, so doesn't fit to the question.

Comment: Great idea. Build the whole shebang from scratch on it, and three years later, when you are _finally_ done, the machine dies on you.