# Load Linux bzImage in QEMU?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel, qemu, x86

I  compiled a Linux by doing `make menuconfig` then `make` and now I have compiled the most recent version of Linux. How can I load the kernel into QEMU?

Comment: Here is a fully automated QEMU + Buildroot setup that just works: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From qemu's help:

```
Linux/Multiboot boot specific:
-kernel bzImage use 'bzImage' as kernel image
-append cmdline use 'cmdline' as kernel command line
-initrd file    use 'file' as initial ram disk
-dtb    file    use 'file' as device tree image
```

A quick test here using Arch's kernel/initrd (`qemu -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux -initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img`) worked (dropped me into a recovery shell since I didn't provide a root device).

Comment: could I just do qemu -kernel linux/arch/x86/boot/bzimage?

Comment: @Coder404 I think so.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try it and let you know the results!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48302/running-bzimage-in-qemu