# Creating a Virtual filesystem to boot linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, boot, linux-kernel, qemu

I am trying to boot the linux kernel (bzImage) in QEMU but have had issues. After asking on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48302/running-bzimage-in-qemu) I found out that my problem was that I was booting the kernel without a filesystem to boot from. So how can I create a VFS to boot the kernel image?

Comment: Your kernel has finished booting already. What you need now is the rest of your operating system - the userland part. What do you want that OS to do? Do you want a minimalist but functional Linux system? Do you want to create that yourself or use an existing distro?

Comment: It has not finished booting. It is looking for a hard drive (qemu's -hda flag). I dont know how to create a virtual hard drive file to make it run.

Comment: See it as you want, what you need is an OS. The kernel's done initializing itself. Now you need a Linux distro to boot.