# Linux kernel is not finding the initrd correctly

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, initrd

I had compiled a linux kernel and I wanted to debug it in QEMU. I created a file to boot from by doing the commands

```
$ qemu-img create -f raw disk.img 200M
$ mkfs.ext2 -F disk.img
# mkdir /mnt/rootfs
# mount -o loop disk.img /mnt/rootfs
```

Then I did `qemu -kernel bzImage -initrd disk.img` and got the screen below which says:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block
```

[image: My QEMU screen]

What have I done wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/2014/06/create-simple-file-system.html

Comment: Same error message as this, but does not specify the steps he took to reach it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48302/running-bzimage-in-qemu-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

Answer (score 10):

What's happening is that you're trying to boot Linux in the "Obsolete" way. That is where the `initrd` is a ramdisk as opposed to a compressed cpio archive unpacked by the kernel in a ramfs, and with the old way to switch to the end device.

In that mode, the kernel mounts the disk.img as a ramdisk as the root file system and then executes `/linuxrc` in there. Most likely in your case, there's no such file. When `/linuxrc` (which is supposed to do whatever's necessary to bring up the block device for the real root filesystem) exits, then the kernel mounts the real root file system.

The messages above show that it mounts the ram disk successfully (1,0: 1 is for `ram`, so `/dev/ram0`) but not the real root file system /dev/sda1 (8,1: 8 is `sd`, 1 is `a1`). Presumably since you didn't specify a kernel command line (`-append`), that `/dev/sda1` comes from a CONFIG_CMDLINE passed at kernel compile time or using `rdev`.

If your disk.img is meant to contain a root file system of say a small Linux distribution with `/sbin/init`..., then you probably want to write it instead:

```
kvm -kernel kernel.img -initrd disk.img -append 'root=/dev/ram0`
```

Then, the kernel would treat the ram disk as the real root file system (though you could still `pivot_root` to another one).

To be able to see the kernel messages more easily, I'd recommend using serial output:

```
kvm -kernel kernel.img -initrd disk.img -nographic -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=ttyS0"
```

As an alternative you could use an init ramfs instead of an init ramdisk:

```
mkdir -p RAMFS/{bin,dev} 
cd RAMFS/bin
cp /bin/busybox .
"$PWD/busybox" --install .
cd ..
cp -a /dev/{null,tty,zero,console} dev
printf '%s\n' "#! /bin/sh -" "exec /bin/sh" > init
chmod +x init
find . | cpio -oHnewc | gzip > ../initramfs.gz
cd ..
kvm -kernel kernel.img -initrd initramfs.gz
```

(provided `busybox` is the statically linked version) and you'll get a shell and other busybox utilities in that kernel).

Note that the kernel now runs `/init` as opposed to `/linuxrc` or `/sbin/init` in that mode.

Comment: Line 3 of the shown output shows, that the kernel mounted the ext2 filesystem of the initramdisk. So it's probably not a missing module.

Comment: Oh yes, I had missed that, thanks @t-8ch. I think I know what's going on and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The kernel is telling you, that it doesn't know which *device* holds the root file system.
Your loop mount isn't necessary. (Unmount it before continuing).

Try a command like

`qemu -kernel bzImage -hda disk.img -append root=/dev/sda`

The `-hda disk.img` parameter tells qemu to simulate a disk device based on your `disk.img`.

The `-append root=/dev/sda` switch is used by qemu to tell the kernel about it's root device. This is done by appending the `root=/dev/sda` to the kernel commandline.
You can compare this to the kernel commandline of your own kernel by doing `cat /proc/cmdline` (This is safe). You should see there a `root` parameter, too.

Comment: How would I unmount the files?

Comment: `umount /mnt/rootfs`

Comment: When I do that I get umount: /mnt/rootfs is not mounted (according to mtab)

Comment: Presumably Coder404 doesn't want to attach a disk to that machine and just run the `init` in the `initrd`. Here you're passing the `disk.img` both as a hard disk and a `initrd` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas thanks about the hint about `-initrd` that shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Shouldn't we use `root=mnt/rootfs` instead of `root=/dev/sda` when using qemu because our root file system resides at mnt/rootfs

Answer (score 1):

**`CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y`**

This kernel config option is also required. It enables initrd support on the Linux kernel.

Luckly Buildroot sets it by default for us when `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO=y` is given.

You then pass the CPIO to QEMU with the `qemu -initrd` option. My full QEMU command is:

```
./buildroot/output.x86_64~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 128M -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0 -smp 1  -M pc -append ' nopat nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y console=ttyS0' -device edu -device lkmc_pci_min -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 -kernel ./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/bzImage  -nographic  -initrd './buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/rootfs.cpio'
```

Here is a minimalistic fully automated Buildroot + QEMU example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/b3868a3b009f2ab44fa6d3db3d174930b3cf7b69#initrd