# Debugging Linux Kernel with QEMU

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, debugging, qemu

I was trying to study the debugging of kernel using QEMU. I tried initially and failed due to the fact that there was no virtual file system. The answers to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48302/running-bzimage-in-qemu) suggests that there should be a virtual file system. But it doesn't talk about how to create virtual FS for kernel debugging and how to pass it over to the qemu. Can you help me out?

Comment: [This blog post](http://markshroyer.com/2013/01/debugging-openbsd-via-qemu/) describes the use of QEMU to debug the OpenBSD kernel but could still be helpful, just replace the OpenBSD-specific parts with the Linux ones.  (The author uses a *complete system image* to debug the kernel; he doesn't just use *a kernel only*.)  What exactly is the step you're stuck with?

Comment: @sr_ Kernel Panic happens. And the warning says:- Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0).

Comment: Try using a minimal filesystem (i.e. try debugging the kernel in its normal environment).  What *bug* is it you're trying to get rid of?  (A panic caused by no root file system doesn't quite qualify as a bug (unless what you're trying to do revolves around [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)))

Comment: I know that does not relate to bug. I am experimenting and not trying to get rid of any bugs as of now :)

Comment: [Here](http://criticalindirection.com/2015/05/26/debugging-linux-kernel-using-qemu/) is a way mentioned to debug the Linux kernel using qemu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the distribution you'd like to use, there are various ways to create a file system image, e.g. [this article](https://sites.google.com/site/4utils/articles/minimal_linux_system/minimal-linux-system-from-scratch) walks you through the laborious way to a *"Linux from Scratch"* system.

*In general*, you'd **either** create a QEMU image using `qemu-img`, fetch some distribution's installation media and *use QEMU* with the installation medium to prepare the image ([this page explains the process for Debian GNU/Linux](http://wiki.debian.org/QEMU#Usage)) **or** use an image prepared by someone else.

[This section of the QEMU Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images) contains all the information you need.

*Edit:*
As Gilles' answer to the linked question suggests, you don't need a full-blown root file system for testing, you could just [use an `initrd` image (say, Arch Linux's initrd like here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47622/11539)

Comment: I have made a debian image. Now how will I choose initrd image for that? In other words, which file will I choose as initrd?

Comment: @sr_ I am using ubuntu 12.04.1 how could I get qemu-img?

Comment: [`packages.ubuntu.com` lets you search for package contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents) ⇒ [`qemu-utils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/qemu-utils)

Comment: @sr_ is qemu-utils the modern day version of qemu-img?

Comment: qemu-img is one of the tools in qemu-utils

Answer (score 3):

**QEMU + GDB step-by-step procedure tested on Ubuntu 16.10 host**

To get started from scratch quickly I've made a minimal fully automated QEMU + Buildroot example at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat Major steps are covered below.

First get a root filesystem `rootfs.cpio.gz`. If you need one, consider:

- a minimal `init`-only executable image: [Custom Linux Distro that runs just one program, nothing else | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122717/custom-linux-distro-that-runs-just-one-program-nothing-else/238579#238579)
- a Busybox interactive system: [What is the smallest possible Linux implementation? | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-smallest-possible-linux-implementation/203902#203902)

Then on the Linux kernel:

```
git checkout v4.9
make mrproper
make x86_64_defconfig
cat <<EOF >.config-fragment
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
EOF
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
make -j"$(nproc)"
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                   -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz -S -s
```

On another terminal, supposing you want to start debugging from `start_kernel`:

```
gdb \
    -ex "add-auto-load-safe-path $(pwd)" \
    -ex "file vmlinux" \
    -ex 'set arch i386:x86-64:intel' \
    -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
    -ex 'break start_kernel' \
    -ex 'continue' \
    -ex 'disconnect' \
    -ex 'set arch i386:x86-64' \
    -ex 'target remote localhost:1234'
```

and we are done!!

For kernel modules see: [How to debug Linux kernel modules with QEMU? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607538/how-to-debug-linux-kernel-modules-with-qemu/44095831#44095831)

For Ubuntu 14.04, GDB 7.7.1, `hbreak` was needed, `break` software breakpoints were ignored. Not the case anymore in 16.10. See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/901944

The messy `disconnect` and what come after it are to work around the error:

```
Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: 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
```

Related threads:

- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13984 might be a GDB bug
- [gdb - Remote 'g' packet reply is too long | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662468/remote-g-packet-reply-is-too-long)
- http://wiki.osdev.org/QEMU_and_GDB_in_long_mode osdev.org is as usual an awesome source for these problems
- https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-discuss/2014-10/msg00069.html

See also:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.rst official Linux kernel "documentation"
- [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642)

Known limitations:

- the Linux kernel does not support (and does not even compile without patches) with `-O0`: [How to de-optimize the Linux kernel to and compile it with -O0? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151235/how-to-de-optimize-the-linux-kernel)
- GDB 7.11 will blow your memory on some types of tab completion, even after the `max-completions` fix: [Tab completion interrupt for large binaries | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597777/tab-completion-interrupt-for-large-binaries) Likely some corner case which was not covered in that patch. So an `ulimit -Sv 500000` is a wise action before debugging. Blew up specifically when I tab completed `file<tab>` for the `filename` argument of `sys_execve` as in: [Can the sys_execve() system call in the Linux kernel receive both absolute or relative paths? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290593/895245)

Comment: Wow....so detailed.   I admired you, and really appreciated it....should go into a blog sir.

Comment: @PeterTeoh thanks! SO is my main blog platform :-)