# Installing qemu-img on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu

I am developing a linux kernel and I am trying to to debug it in QEMU. I want to be able to run it in QEMU but it stops because I do not have a virtual hard drive to boot it(using the -hda command). I read in [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61122/debugging-linux-kernel-with-qemu) that a virtual hard drive could be created with qemu-img but I could not download it by doing `sudo apt-get install qemu-img` or `sudo apt-get qemu-img` I also read that qemu-img could be accessed from qemu-utils but i was unable to download that also. How can I download qemu-img on my ubuntu laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing qemu, qemu-system and qemu-kvm should be all you need. Just make sure you have the universe repository enabled.

Comment: universe repository?

Comment: Yes, see here for details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu .

Comment: qemu-system is automatically installed to satisfy qemu's dependencies.  At least it is in 16.04

Answer (score 5):

I have the same question, but I'm using Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.

It worked doing

```
apt-get install qemu-utils
```